# How to Initialize a static class object from a static class function

Tags: c++, class, static, initialization, static-methods

Initializing the static member TestClassObject showing an error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol.

```cpp
    class TestClass
            {
            public:
                string sClassName;
                string sName;
                string sDescription;


            };

    class TestA
            {

            private:
                static void InitInfo();  
                static TestClass TestClassObject;
            };

    void TestA::InitInfo()
    {
        TestClassObject.sName = "Name";
        TestClassObject.sClassName = "ClassName";
        TestClassObject.sDescription = "Description of class";

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to define the static data member outside the class definition. Within the class definition it is only declared but not defined.

For example

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class TestClass
        {
        public:
            string sClassName;
            string sName;
            string sDescription;


        };

class TestA
        {

        private:
            static TestClass InitInfo();  
            static TestClass TestClassObject;
        };

TestClass TestA::InitInfo()
{
    return { "Name", "ClassName", "Description of class" };
}    

TestClass TestA::TestClassObject = InitInfo();

int main()
{
}
```

Comment: Do i Need to manually Call InitInfo() for initializing the variables. Or only I need to call is the variable TestClassObject?

Comment: @HariSankarvm If you provide a constructor to your class instead of your `initInfo` function, you could just create the object directly: `TestClass TestA::testClassObject("name", "class", "description");`

Comment: @HariSankarvm You want to initialize the object by the function. So you should provide a function call to initialize the object.

Comment: @HariSankarvm You could alternatively leave the return type as `void` and call `TestA::initInfo()` from within `main`. That's especially interesting if you want to call it multiple times, as you don't need the assignment any more (but it would then probably better be called `reset`...).

Comment: @HariSankarvm Without the function you can just write TestClass TestA::TestClassObject  = { "Name", "ClassName", "Description of class" };

Comment: Actually I need to access the variable TestClassObject before creating the instance of TestA class. Thats why I gave a static variable and static function for accessing the variable

Comment: @HariSankarvm That's all fine so far. But the function to initialise won't call itself just for fun, you need to do that explicitly *somewhere*...

Comment: @HariSankarvm Or you skip that function completely in favour of initialising the object directly via constructor or aggregate initialisation (Vlad's last comment). Of the latter I'm not very fond of myself, at least as long as we don't have designated initialisers (coming with C++20), as it is not robust against changing order of variables in the class...

Comment: ok. Thank you so much for the support. my  issue got resolved. Actually I tried a method like this before. But at that time it was not working. Now its working fine